# Auto incrementing field that begins with text in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am searching for a way to auto increment an ArcGIS field which begins with text and followed by numbers. Ex. SWCL0000. I have tried the auto increment code in the field calculator but once I added text and a starting number, I kept on getting errors.

Comment: So you're looking to have like A01, A02, A03.. like a specific string + auto increment, correct?  Or are you looking to just add 1 to existing values?  Basically, do the values exist already and you're updating them or do they need created?

Comment: Yes I am basically using a specific string and autoincrement.

Answer (score 5):

I borrowed a lot of the code [from here](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38517).  Try this.

Turn on the `python parser` in the Field Calculator.

*Pre-Logic Script Code:*

```
rec = 0
def autoInc():
  global rec
  pStart = 1
  pInterval = 1
  if (rec == 0):
    rec = pStart
  else:
    rec += pInterval
  return rec
```

*FieldName* =

`"SWCL" + str(autoInc()).zfill(4)`

The [`.zfill()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm) function makes sure your string is at least *n* characters long and will pad with zeroes.

Comment: Branco's exactly right. There are some examples in the ESRI help docs including the example above [at this link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F3F8CD77A9F647ABBA678A76ADB86E15) under "Accumulative and sequential calculations".

Comment: @John Thanks for posting that link.  I had no idea there was a collection of examples like that.  I took the above one from a random code download thing ESRI had.  I think it was when they had the scripts to download pages and such.  Great resource!!